# Special character combination "?/" not being interpreted correctly in XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-4.0

For our top menu, we use a custom control that essentially reads from an XML file. The name of the control is `SCS.MultiMenu`.

One of the menuitems is a report whose link is the following:

```
http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/MyReport
```

The report generates correctly with that URL.

So, in the XML file, the menuitem looks like this:

```
<MenuItem Text="My report"  
Url="http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/Report"
PostBack="False"/>
```

When I click on this menuitem, I'm redirected to the following link, which is incorrect: `http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?` As you can see, it removed everything after the question mark.

I tried using escape sequences to see if it accepts the correct URL (ie. ? for *question mark (?)* and / for slash) but it continues cutting everything after the "?". I tried something like this:

```
http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx&#63;&#47;Folder/MyReport
```

What could the issue be? I even tried switching every single character to escpae sequences, but did not work.

I'm thinking that it's possibly an error in this menu control, but it wouldn't make sense.

I'm including everything I've tried and what the URL looks like when I click on it:

```
http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/MyReport
>> http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?

http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?path=%2FFolder%2FReport
>> http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?path=/Folder/Report&

http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx&#63;&#47;Folder/MyReport
>> http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?

http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/MyReport=
>> http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/MyReport=&

http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?=/Folder/MyReport  
>> http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?=/Folder/MyReport&
```

Thanks

Comment: `/` can not be used query part of the url, I think your url should be  `http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?path=%2FFolder%2FReport` Hint: *`WebUtility.UrlEncode("/Folder/Report")`*

Comment: I don't think it's the `/`. If I switch the `?/` so the `/` is before the `?`, everything after the `?` will be cut. So the resulting link would look like `http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx/?`

Comment: Percent encoding doesn't work. I switched every `/` after `ReportViewer.aspx` to `%2F`, and it just takes me to `http://myserver/ReportServer`

Comment: I did, and it actually displays the whole link, but with a `=&` at the end. It redirects me to `http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/MyReport=&`. Unfortunately, those two chars at the end, for some reason, display the contents of `/ReportServer/`

Comment: You can see the `http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/MyReport=&` in the address bar, but the contents of `http://myserver/ReportServer` in the browser.

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with XML?

Comment: @wero, sorry for the delay. I was called to a meeting. The issue was not solved by adding the `=` char.

Comment: @MichaelKay, it is related to an XML file. Then again, you would know that had you _read_ the whole post. Why on earth didn't you read?

Comment: @rbhatup your original question is answered: it is the library that munges the URL. Unfortunately there is no way to make it render your URL correctly. But you can still grab the library sources and build a patched version.

Comment: @wero, it's possible you're right. Anyways, I ended up using another library to create the menu. Should I just delete this question? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rbhatup Sorry if I was impolite. A lot of people tag questions with "xml" just because there is some XML somewhere in the system. Reading more carefully, I now see that you genuinely thought it was something to do with the fact that the URL is in an XML file. I think that's almost certainly a blind alley, but I can see now why you went up it.

Comment: @MichaelKay, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [library](http://multimenu.codeplex.com/releases/view/42574) handles the url of a menu item in a special way:

It cuts of the querystring from the url and parses it:

1. split by `&` into single parameters
2. split by `=` into name value pairs.

(see `QueryString.cs`)

If no `=` is present in step 2 the parameter is silently discarded, and that is why
your querystring `/Folder/Report` vanishes.

You could try if `/Folder/Report=` or `=/Folder/Report` survive this treatment and are accepted by your server.